# How to limit the depth of analysis in Arena?

Tags: analysis, stockfish

I am using `Arena` with `Stockfish-222-64-ja-intel`. It thinks about 50 moves deep and heats up my laptop processor. All I was interested in, was a depth of about 12-13 moves and for the best line to be shown on the top. I am not able to find the options to configure the gui is such a manner. Let me know if you have an answer.

Update: I know how to limit the level for computer strength. That's plain - it's `Levels>>Adjust>>Fixed Search Depth>>8 half moves`. The problem still persists though. When I click the `Analyze` button, the computer starts thinking really deep (and yes, the heating problem is a bit irritating and drains the battery).

Comment: `8 half moves` means from 8 moves for each side. if you want 12-13 moves, reduces it to Levels>>Adjust>>Fixed Search Depth>>`6 half moves`.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is limit the number of cores Stockfish has access to. I'm sure your computer/laptop has more than one core, but if improperly set, a UCI engine can eat up all of your processing power and leave your computer sluggish. There are two ways to fix this.

Arena should have a "Lower than normal process priority" in Engine Management Options. You should check this off.

Also, I know Chessbase lets you allocate a certain amount of cores (or threads) for the engine, and I'm sure Arena does as well. However, I'm not entirely sure how to do it with the specified software.

Comment: While addressing the overheating, this can just be annoying when you only want a 12-13 move depth. I too find this frustrating - if I just make a move, the resulting engine honors the 8 move deep setting. But if I click analyze, it will go for ever! So I'm not sure this really answers teh question.